# Are there any MySQL functions to get all rows with with a start or end date that fall between a given start and end date?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of events with a recorded start and end time as a MySQL DATETIME object (in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. I want to find all events that occur in a specific date range. However, events can span multiple days (and go outside of my date range, but I want to return them if they even overlap by 1 second or more with my date range).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will find every event that is completely contained inside the range:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date BETWEEN start_of_range AND end_of_range 
                      AND stop_date  BETWEEN start_of_range AND end_of_range
```

This will find any events where any part of the event overlaps any part of the range:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date <= end_of_range 
                      AND stop_date  >= start_of_range
```

Answer (score 7):

The answers by @Bill the Lizard and @Robert Gamble are correct for the question as asked, but I do wonder if you're asking what you think you are... If you're looking for overlapping events then you need to take into account events longer than your search range.

```
           Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday

Search:                |-----------|

Shopping                       |-----|              Found OK
Eating              |--------|                      Found OK
Stack Overflow |---------------------------------|  Not found!
```

If you wanted to include SO, you'd do:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (start_date < end_of_range AND end_date > start_of_range)`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE startdate >= 'starting date' AND startdate < 'ending date'
    OR enddate >= 'starting date' AND enddate < 'ending date'
```

should work for you.

Make sure you specify 'starting date' and 'ending date' with the time included.

```
'2008-01-01 00:00:00'' AND '2008-01-31 23:59:59'
```

This will help to avoid errors where dates are the same, but your time falls within the interval by a few hours, minutes, or seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can use regular comparisons -- the ones above should work -- the trick is to check all the different cases that can occur.

A) events with an ending date within the range

B) events with a starting date within the range

C) events with both starting and ending dates within the range

D) events with both starting and ending dates *outside* the range, but overlapping it

Robert's answer is a good one, but it doesn't take into account case D, where the event starts before the range and ends after the range.

Comment: If you cover either A or B, you don't have to worry about C.

Comment: You're totally right, I was just trying illustrate all the possible ways an event could overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Llya, Roberts answer with,

SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date <= end_of_range 
                      AND stop_date  >= start_of_range

works fine with,

D) events with both starting and ending dates outside the range, but overlapping it

??