# Are there any MySQL functions to get all rows with with a start or end date that fall between a given start and end date? - Part 2

Tags: mysql

In a follow up on [seperate question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277953/are-there-any-mysql-functions-to-get-all-rows-with-with-a-start-or-end-date-that): I'm running into the issue that from the thousands of records a correct index cant really be used.

I came up with the provided answer some time ago by myself and have it implemented for a while now. Now there are several thousand events in a database (seperate indexes on startdatetime and enddatetime columns) but the mysql interperter cant really use them because of the query itself:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date <= end_of_range
                      AND stop_date  >= start_of_range
```

Am i correct in thinking this cant easily be optimized further? (having to look trough 40K records just to know which events occur today (or any other range for that matter)

My question: how do the bigger applications solve this issue?

More information after the comments below:
Query:

`EXPLAIN SELECT id
FROM  event
WHERE startDatetime <=  '2011-03-31 23:59:59'
AND  endDatetime >=  '2011-03-01 00:00:00'`

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  event   ALL startDatetime,endDatetime   NULL    NULL    NULL    58331   Using where
```

In other words: the entire table? Now just to be clear: the query isnt by definition slow, but it doesnt use any index either... ?

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on both start_date and stop_date (both columns in one index)?

Comment: Would that matter since i dont select a range per column? ( start_date and stop_date are two different columns)

(BTW tried it though without avail)

Comment: can you post the EXPLAIN plan?

Comment: edited the question with the explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably describing a non problem.

In your test query mysql is considering to use 2 indexes (and that's all you can ask of it): it uses none because statistics tell it that table scan will be more efficient compared to index.

I assume that in your example your test query is not selective enough to trigger the use of the indexes (your test case deals with 1 month range of data - what is the percentage of data that satisfy the condition? according to each of the indexes?).

The only thing that you can improve is to create a composite index, as I think that in your example mysql's [index merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) will not be able to help you. So, do realize that it is a different situation to have

- 2 indexes, one on `startDateTime` and on on `endDateTime`

compared to

- 1 composite index on `(startDateTime, endDateTime)`

This index should be most useful for events that start within a range and apply additional criteria on `endDateTime`.

You might also consider having another index: `(endDateTime, startDateTime)` (this one should help the most for queries that look for events that end within the range and apply additional criteria on `startDateTime`).

You might also read up on [table scans](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html) and see how forcing an index or modifying some server side variables might effect your performance.

Comment: The entire table spans more than 6 years, and even if i lower the range to a 24hour period, it doesnt help ... still the full scan...
BTW adding the indexes / composite index didnt help any...

Comment: As I asked above - what is the percentage of data that actually satisfy your criteria?

Comment: Also, try to force an index and see what happens (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html). If your query then performs worse then mysql is doing a good thing.

Comment: selecting a 24hour period gives 49 rows out of the total of 79727 but still uses a full table scan!

the problem with this query to me is that it uses single criteria per index and thus cant really trim the results down quickly...

Comment: That's why composite index should do the trick. Did you try to create (endDateTime, startDateTime), too?

Comment: On the matter of forcing the index: i'm a profound believer that i cant outthink mysql ;) and thus forcing mysql to select an index over its own algorithms seems wrong...

Comment: Yes, on the matter of forcing the index I agree (not that one should try to outsmart the planner, but that forcing indexes is bad approach). Still, use it to compare execution plans and find out more.

Comment: BTW the (endDate, startDate) combined index is used, whilst (startDate, endDate) isnt. But the rows counted is still 30K ? So atleast an index can be used now, but not to real effect (so it seems)

Comment: @Gekkie, `rows` counted is just an estimate, once an access path had been chosen the engine will walk that particular path in the most effective way. You could check http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_Optimizer#The_Optimizer to read more on how mysql optimizer works

Comment: So, what your saying is the fact that it now does use the composite index this will probably be the best possible solution? (index being endDate,StartDate and not the other way around since mysql didnt use that anyway?

Comment: @Gekkie, well, obviously the row estimate is not very precise (few orders of magnitude off), so theoretically it still might not be the best access path. Also, given that you need to select 70 records out of 60k records it is not clear what would be absolutely ideal access path (maybe still table range scan?). However, given your description of columns and data this index sounds like the best one for this particular query (with different days however...)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is backward, and is making the server scan too many records to make the match.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date >= start_of_range 
                      AND stop_date <= end_of_range
```

This will take advantage of the indexes, because it can quickly locate start_date and then only move forward in the index. It can also position the index you have on the stop_date quickly, and then only has to scan rows backward.

Comment: But your query returns the wrong results? The original problem remains: events that start before but end within the range, start within the range but end outside the range, events that start and end within the range and last but not least events that start before and and after the range...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to divide the problem in two, and then mix the results.

```
SELECT * FROM table t INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE start_date <= end_of_range
    ) AS sd ON t.id = sd.id INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE end_date >= start_of_range
    ) AS ed ON t.id = ed.id
```

I'm assuming you have a `PRIMARY` key on `table` named `id`, this will probably use the indexes on the `start_date` and `end_date` columns, but will use temporary tables for merging the results.

If the events table keeps growing you might want to use temporary tables instead of derived tables. Populate the temp tables first with just the `id` of the events, then create indexes on the `id` column of the temp tables, finally do the join.

Comment: What you propose is a bad strategy - temp tables are the last option (scalability and complexity that translates to maintenance issues), that can be a gain if you reuse certain result-sets (and can forfeit consistency in particular scenario) - so as cache/session tables they can make sense, but the above advice is really not good as a general approach.

Comment: @Unreason, so how would you go about optimizing the query in question?

Comment: read my answer. First thing to try would be composite indexes. Second, he might be dealing with a non problem (it is clearly stated that the query does not perform bad, it is just that he would want to see DB use indexes - which it will as selectivity on existing and usable index reaches certain threshold). Going for temp tables at this stage is almost certainly premature optimization (the root of all evil - D.Knuth) plus it might not even be optimization, but might have contra effect