# Count days of a date interval (period) inside another given date interval (period)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, intervals, between

I had a problem but part was solving thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277953/are-there-any-mysql-functions-to-get-all-rows-with-with-a-start-or-end-date-that), but know i want to know how can i count the days beetween a given interval.

It is a query to count how many days an employee goes to vacation. So given (or not given) a date range, i would like count how many vacation days are beetween given interval.

Currenty my SQL is like this:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(vacation_end_date,vacation_start_date))
FROM vacation WHERE vacation_end_date >= given_start_date 
AND vacation_start_date <= given_end_date'
```

I know thatthe DATEDIFF will only work for days inside given range, but it shouldn't count days outside from given range.

Please help me, couldn't find something similar on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If vacation_end_date is the day the person is *back* from vacation and not his last day vacationing, the query to get the person's vacation days between 2012-01-01 (inclusive) and 2013-01-01 (exclusive) would be;

```
SELECT SUM(
 GREATEST(0, 
  DATEDIFF(
   LEAST('2013-01-01', vacation_end_date),
   GREATEST('2012-01-01', vacation_start_date)
))) 'VACATION_DAYS'
FROM vacation;
```

If vacation_end_date is his last vacation day, you'll need to replace vacation_end_date with `ADDDATE(vacation_end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))` in the query above to get the calculation correct.

Simple demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0275f/9).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, using `COUNT` should get you what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(
        DATEDIFF(vacation_end_date,
            if(vacation_start_date < given_start_date, 
                given_start_date,
                vacation_start_date)
        )
    )
FROM vacation WHERE vacation_end_date >= given_start_date 
AND vacation_start_date <= given_end_date'
```

Comment: No, because if vacation starts before given date, (example 3 days before) it will count those 3 days. I would like to start counting in this case from given date.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, in this case it'll evaluate if vacation starts before given date, and if it does it'll coun based on the given date (the same is can be done if you need the same conditions for vacation_end_date)

Comment: Thanks it worked but the another solution is simpler. Thanks for the quick response.